# Simple sound-mixer

Tags: schematics, sound

I'm trying to make simple sound-mixer. I've found this scheme.
[image: Simple mixer]

Can I connect passive-pickup guitar to `MICRO` input? Which holes has that scheme? And can I increase inputs by just copying existing.

---

> P.S. I'll miss phones-output block so as I needn't him.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I connect passive-pickup guitar to MICRO input?

No, a passive guitar pick-up needs a high input impedance amplifier. The "micro" input has an input impedance of 1 kohm (if I read your diagram correctly). The OPAMP is configured as an inverting amplifier with a gain of 100 and the 1 kohm resistor connects to what is known as a virtual earth (or ground) so, the 1 kohm is, in effect, from input to ground. You need to look for a guitar pre-amp circuit that has an input impedance of 100 kohm or greater. There are plenty of examples around on the internet such as this one: -

[image]

Notice the high value input resistors. If you use low value ones, you greatly attenuate the high frequencies produced by the pick-up and the sound is muddy.